# How to do math operations in the Controller and then display them in blade

Tags: laravel, math, controller, laravel-blade

I am at a low level of Laravel and PHP advancement. All my knowledge is based on YouTube tutorials, Laravel documentation and online forums.

To deepen my knowledge, I decided to create an application project that would calculate the price based on constant values ​​and variables (entered by the user). The constants are in one table, they are put in there by me and cannot be changed. Variable values ​​are entered by the user.

At the moment, I managed to make a connection to the database (full CRUD), however, I cannot cope with the formula for calculating many records from two tables. I don't know how to perform math calculations in Controller and then display them in Blade.

I do not expect ready code, but only advice on what method to use or whether I made a mistake while creating the tables. I am asking for help and thank you to those who made it to the end of this post.

The first table with constant values ​​looks like this:
constant_costs

| id | cost_name | amount_of_cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Tax_01 | 1.36 |
| 2 | Tax_02 | 0.15 |
| 3 | Tax_03 | 0.08 |
| 4 | Transport | 0.37 |
| 5 | Margin_01 | 0.26 |
| 6 | Margin_02 | 0.10 |

The second table, the value of which is added by the user by the form (I entered some sample numbers below):
stuff

| id | value_01 | value_02 | value_03 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 4 | 20 |

The formula for the price is a bit complicated:
(((value_01 / 159 + Margin_01) * value_02) + Tax_01 + Tax_02 + Tax_03 + Transport + Margin_02) * value_03

When I put the accessor in the Model, I get an error: BadMethodCallException Method Illuminate \ Database \ Eloquent \ Collection :: getFormulaCalculation does not exist.

```
In my Model
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Casts\Attribute;

class stuff extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    public $timestamps = FALSE;

    protected $fillable = ['value_01', 'value_02', 'value_03'];

    /**
     * Price formula
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Casts\Attribute
     */
    public function getFormulaCalculationAttribute(): Attribute
    {
        return Attribute::make(
            get: fn ($value) => (($this->value_01 / 159 + 0.26) * $this->value_02) + 1.369 + 0.15261 + 0.08 + 0.37 + 0.1 * $this->value_03);
    }
}

In my Controller
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\stuff;

public function result()
    {
        public function result()
    {
        $stuff = stuff::all();
        $getFormulaCalculationAttribute = $stuff->getFormulaCalculation();

        return view('stuff.result')->with('getFormulaCalculationAttribute', $getFormulaCalculationAttribute);
    }
    }
```

Comment: why do you add the constants in DB if they will never change "or this will rarely happen", it will be better to add them in the config file, no need to hit the DB for getting those values every time you need to use them in a calculation

Comment: The first table I posted has one more column: cost_description. I did not write it here in this question because I meant mathematical operations. one of the files in the views folder displays the following columns: cost_name, cost_description, and amount_of_cost. That's why I decided to make a table. After reading your answer, I find it was not a good idea after all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't get the idea from creating a table for constant values, there is a simple solution to create this calculation in your Eloquent model.

you can create an Accessor for your formula something like this

```
public function getFormulaCalculationAttribute()
{
    return ((($this->value_01 / 159 + Margin_01) * $this->value_02) + Tax_01 + Tax_02 + Tax_03 + Transport + Margin_02) * $this->value_03;
}
```

just replace the constant with your values

after that, you can call this attribute like this

```
echo $value->formula_calculation;
```

please pay attention to your laravel version starting from laravel 9 defining an accessor is different
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor

or for laravel 9

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor

I hope it's helpful

Comment: as soon as I can I will try it out with your method. I will let you know how it went

Comment: I did according to the documentation of Laravel 9 (or at least I think so). When I put the accessor in the Model, I get an error: BadMethodCallException Method Illuminate \ Database \ Eloquent \ Collection :: getFormulaCalculation does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Instead of putting a formula for the price in the Controller, I put it in the Model. Then I referred to it in Laravel Blade. Thank you for your help

```
Model
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class stuff extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    public $timestamps = FALSE;

    protected $fillable = ['value_01', 'value_02', 'value_03'];

    
     //Price formula
     public function PriceFormula()
     {
        return ((($this->value_01 / 159 + 0.26) * $this->value_02) + 1.369 + 0.15261 
        + 0.08 + 0.37 + 0.1) * $this->value_03 / 100 + 1);
     }
}

Controller
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\stuff;

public function result()
    {
        public function result()
        $stuff = stuff::all();
        return view('stuff.result')->with('stuff', $stuff);
    }
}

Laravel Blade
@foreach ($stuff as $stuf)
    {{ $stuf->PriceFormula() }}
@endforeach
```